# Error Route [docente.actualizarusuario] not defined."

Tags: laravel

Tengo definidas las rutas

```
Route::patch('misvistas/docente/{id}', 'DocenteController@actualizarusuario');
Route::resource('misvistas/docente', 'DocenteController');
```

Al ejecutar `php artisan route:list` aparece en la lista actualizarusuario.

Pero al intentar ejecutar la función "actualizarusuario" sale el error:

```
Route [docente.actualizarusuario] not defined.
```

Comment: Aparte de que te falta un punto y coma, no veo que le estés asignando ningún alias a la ruta para poder llamarla por el. Deberías añadirle el nombre/alias a la ruta: `->name('docente.actualizarusuario');`

Comment: ¿Cómo intenta imprimir la ruta en su vista?

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funcionó.

Comment: @Dev. Joel la ruta quedo asi: 'Route::patch('misvistas/docente/{id}/actualizarusuario', 'DocenteController@actualizarusuario')->name('docente.actualizarusuario');'

Comment: @RicardoGarciaOlais te añado respuesta para que quede constancia. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas creando la ruta de la siguiente manera:

```
Route::patch('misvistas/docente/{id}', 'DocenteController@actualizarusuario');
```

Pero por el error que te da la esta intentando llamar por un alias o nombre que nunca ha sido declarado (`docente.actualizarusuario`):

```
Route [docente.actualizarusuario] not defined.
```

Para poder utilizar el alias de la ruta antes debes declararlo con `name()`, quedando la definición de la ruta así:

```
Route::patch('misvistas/docente/{id}', 'DocenteController@actualizarusuario')->name('docente.actualizarusuario');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probando con ***Laravel 5.1*** no encontre ningun error.

Con las rutas que indicas:

```
Route::patch('misvistas/docente/{id}', 'DocenteController@actualizarusuario');
Route::resource('misvistas/docente', 'DocenteController');
```

Y un controlador como el siguiente:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class DocenteController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo(get_class() . ' / index() <hr>');
    }

    public function actualizarusuario($id)
    {
        echo(get_class() . ' / actualizarusuario() -> ID: ' . $id . '<hr>');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        echo(get_class() . ' / show() -> ID: ' . $id . '<hr>');
    }


} //class
```

Si haces la petición GET:

```
http://tuapp.com/misvistas/docente/1
```

Obtienes:

> App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController / show() -> ID: 1

Si haces la petición PATCH (y has desactivado previamente la protección CSRF*):

```
http://tuapp.com/misvistas/docente/1
```

Obtienes:

> App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController / actualizarusuario() -> ID: 1

Al listar las rutas usando artisan:

```
php artisan route:list
```

aparece entre otras la ruta que has definido:

```
PATCH    | misvistas/docente/{id}           |
   | App\Http\Controllers\DocenteController@actualizarusuario
```

Revisa que estas usando el verbo correcto en la petición y tu controlador a ver si tienes alguna diferencia.

*Desactivar protección CSRF (sólo para pruebas en local, volver a activar más tarde):
Ir a la clase "app/Http/Kernel.php" y comentar la línea de la propiedad `$middleware`:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```